# Strange characters showing up in XML > ASP.NET > Javascript > HTML

Tags: asp.net, javascript, xml, vb.net

i have a script that reads an xml file then produces some document.write javascript lines and sends them to request .  I'm getting a weird character (only shows in internet explorer, not firefox).  I can't seem to track it down.

Here's a URL of the script being used (has weird chars in IE): http://www.voyagertravelguides.com/test.htm

The source of the javascript tag is where the .net script is

Anyone know what's up? I've tried using ISO-8859-1 on both the script and in a meta tag.  I've tried replacing chr(194) in the .NET script

Comment: Where on the page is the weird character showing up?

Comment: Chris, I don't see weird characters in IE8, with or without compatibility mode. Where should I see the weird characters? The only odd thing I see is that you should URL-encode the URL to the script - you've got spaces in the URL.

Comment: Well, I just changed it to UTF-8 and it's not showing up anymore.  Maybe that was the issue.  Was very weird.  mainly just randomly between some lines you would see an acute capital A

Answer (score 0):

If you use WriteAllText or WriteAllLines to create the xml file, it can introduce odd characters if you don't specify the encoding scheme.

For example, instead of

```
   File.WriteAllText(fName, sText)
```

use

```
   File.WriteAllText(fName, sText, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```